# Is there a way to capture any character along with newline at the end?

Tags: regex, java-8

I'm working on this TDD tutorial exercise that centers around creating and testing a string calculator. I'm at the step where you create a customize a delimiter. The input should be something like this `//[delimiter]\n[numbers…]` an accepted input should be something like `//%\n5%2%5`.

I'm adding to the regex step by step and I've hit a brick wall. I am currently only trying to match the `//[delimiter]\n` part. How do I match any character (including newline) while keeping the closing newline? For example, `.*` keeps gobbling up the entire string, `.+?` only takes one character. I have also tried to use `//.*(?=\n)` but still no match. I suspect that I have to use a lookahead but how do I implement this properly?

The link to this problem is http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/. Any pointers are appreciated and have a great day.

Comment: In Java 8, you can use `\R` to match a line break regardless of whether it is unix style `\n` or Windows like `\r\n` or whatever else. Further, keep in mind that putting these regular expressions into a Java string literal requires quoting each backslash with another backslash, as they have a meaning in Java string literals as well. Beyond that, if you still have problems, you have to provide your code, to enable us to reproduce your problem. It won’t help you if we have to guess.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just match numbers and then add the add the groups together?

```
String input = "//[***]\n1***2*\n**3";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int total = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        total += Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(0));
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

1.3 of the question states *solve things as simply as possible*. Matching for all digits and adding them togheter supports delimiters etc. since it doesn't matter what content is between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your program reads the data line-by-line (same as sed). If not, the following should work:

> //(.*?)\n\d+(\1\d+)+

- delimiter can be any sequence of characters
- there is an unlimited number of numbers to be separated (on the second line).

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/ocuJMB/2)